# React - problems with filtering fetched data from global context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a simple app showing items with prices on them. I created a global context as my global state. I'm trying to make a filter component where I can filter the items that I get from the context - filtering the items by prices (sort by highest or lowest).

Here's my filter component:

```
import * as React from "react";

const Filter = ({ updateFilter }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (prop, value) => {
    setState({
      [prop]: value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <form onChange={() => updateFilter(state)} noValidate>
          <select
            value={state.sortOrder}
            onChange={(event) =>
              handleChange("sortItems", event.target.value)
            }
          >
            <option value="">Choose...</option>
            <option value="highest">Highest</option>
            <option value="lowest">Lowest</option>
          </select>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

Here's the home component that is using the filter component above:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Filter from "./shared/Filter";
import Card from "./Card";
import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";

const defaultState = {
  sortItems: "",
};

const Home = () => {
  const { items } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(defaultState);

  const applyFilter = (items, filter) => {
    const { sortItems } = filter;
    let data = items;

    if (sortItems) {
      if (sortItems === "") {
        return data;
      }
      if (sortItems === "highest") {
        data = data.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
      }
      if (sortItems === "lowest") {
        data = data.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
      }
    }
    return data;
  };

  const updateFilter = (filter) => {
    setFilter(filter);
  };

  const filteredItems = applyFilter(items, filter);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Filter updateFilter={updateFilter} />
      <div>
        {filteredItems.map((listing) => (
          <Link
            to={`items/${item.id}`}
          >
            <Card key={listing.id} listing={listing} />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );  
};

export default Home;
```

For reference - `items` from my global context is returning an array of items like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Item A",
    "category": "A",
    "price": 10000 
  },
  ...
  ..
  ..
]
```

The problem I'm having is now is that when I selected a filter for the first time, for example - `Highest`,  and I consoled log `filteredItems`, it was giving me the same unfiltered items from context. I then selected `Lowest`, when I consoled log my `filteredItems`, it gave what I selected previously which was `Highest` and my items are sorted from the highest price.

Why is there a lag in the `filteredItems`? What did I do wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What you're referring to, seems to be ***sorting*** rather than *filtering*. Would you provide live snippet (e.g. at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Also, pay attention that `.sort()` mutates input array (`items` in your particular case). If you intend to make a copy of `items` into `data`, you would need to do `const data = [...items]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-wind-4gcbf?file=/src/GlobalContext.js

Some notes:

1. Your applyFilter sets the data variable to reference items, and because sort mutates, you're mutating state through the reference. Instead, I conditionally sorted a copy of items in the return.
2. While not directly using index as your iteration key, your item ids are linear and would impact react's tracking ability.

Comment: Thank you so much and will keep in mind about the notes!